# How do you get how many days passed from the previous Tuesday (or any day name) until DateTime.Now or todays date?

Tags: c#

Not sure how to go about this.
I can find todays date.

```
string now = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("Today is: " + now);
```

then I have a string that could be any day of the week but no date for it.
So lets say all I have is:

```
string day = "Thursday";
```

How do I subtract that day (example being Thursday) from now (Monday or todays date 8/15/2022)?
What I'm after is the actual date.
In this case it would be 8/11/2022
Even getting the number of days from any given day till now would be helpful.

Comment: The title says that you want a count of days and the question says you want a date. Which is it? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question, then summarise the question you asked in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain an offset map of `System.DayOfWeek` that allows you to offset `DateTime.Now` based on the current `DayOfWeek`.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var dayOfWeek = now.DayOfWeek;
    
var offset = dayOfWeek switch
{
    DayOfWeek.Monday => -6,
    DayOfWeek.Sunday => -5,
    DayOfWeek.Saturday => -4,
    DayOfWeek.Friday => -3,
    DayOfWeek.Thursday => -2,
    DayOfWeek.Wednesday => -1,
    DayOfWeek.Tuesday => -7, // or 0, depending on your needs;
    _ => 0
};

var lastTuesday = now.AddDays(offset);

Console.WriteLine(lastTuesday.Date); // Outputs 8/9/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use enum calculations:

```
    int DaysSince(DayOfWeek dow)
    {
        var today = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        return (7 + today - dow) % 7;
    }

    var daysSince = DaysSince(DateOfWeek.Tuesday);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I have based this answer on the actual question, that says you want a date, rather than the title, which says you want a count of days. If you follow the method below, you can increment a variable in the loop to get a count of days.

Here's one option:

```cs
private static DateTime GetDateOfLastDayOfWeek(string dayName)
{
    if (!Enum.TryParse(dayName, false, out DayOfWeek dayOfWeek))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid day of week", nameof(dayName));
    }

    var date = DateTime.Today;

    do
    {
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    } while (date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek);

    return date;
}
```

Note that, if today is the specified day, it will go back to the previous instance. If you wanted to match today's date, you could use a `while` loop instead of a `do`:

```cs
while (date.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
{
    date = date.AddDays(-1);
}
```